Adding an object to autodesk forge viewer
Is it possible to add an object to forge viewer. I know that it is possible to add custom geometry using three.js, but I want to add an object that will be part of the model I'm uploading. Have the same properties and so on
I used to use the Draw Tool Extension in order to add objects, but they are added specifically to the scene, they cannot be selected, you cannot adjust their indicators.

Using the Scene Builder extension, you can create models and add your own objects to Viewer SDK.
